# useRef is not working in nextjs for react-pdf package

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-pdf

I have rendered pdf in react using react-pdf package and in page component of package it is exposing one property name canvasRef but it is not attaching any event listener with that ref

```
import React from "react";
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from "react-pdf";
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
import styles from "../../pages/edit-pdf/editPdf.module.css";
const PDFViewer = () => {
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = React.useState<number>();
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = React.useState<number>(1);
  const pdfRef = React.useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  function handleMouseDown(
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLCanvasElement, MouseEvent>
  ): void {
    console.log("calling the function");
    if (pdfRef.current) {
      let rect = pdfRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      let x = event.clientX - rect.left;
      let y = event.clientY - rect.top;
      console.log("Coordinate x: " + x, "Coordinate y: " + y);
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const canvasElement = pdfRef.current;
    if (canvasElement) {
      console.log("found canvas element", canvasElement);
      pdfRef.current?.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown as any);
      return () => {
        pdfRef.current?.removeEventListener(
          "mousedown",
          handleMouseDown as any
        );
      };
    }
  }, []);

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }: { numPages: number }): void {
    setNumPages(numPages);
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.pdf_provider_main}>
      {/* <canvas ref={pdfRef}></canvas> */}
      <div className="container_main">
        <Document
          file={{ url: "nodedev.pdf" }}
          onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        >
          <Page
            renderAnnotationLayer={false}
            renderTextLayer={false}
            pageNumber={pageNumber}
            className={styles.pdf_page}
            canvasRef={pdfRef}
          ></Page>
        </Document>
        <p style={{ margin: "0px", padding: "10px", textAlign: "center" }}>
          Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PDFViewer;
```

in above code  i have commented canvas element but if i use that element to test it is working but if i use same for canvasRef it is not adding any eventlistner to it